# Do not generate file in disk, instead send mail with data in memory

Tags: asp-classic

I have a piece of code that works and do:

Reads a Database , reads a template (template.htm), put data in a new file based in the template (evento.htm), read that file and send an email with the content of the file generated. Code below (I cut the database part):

```
<%
    NomeDoTemplate= "template.htm"
    CaminhoDoTemplate= Server.MapPath(NomeDoTemplate)
    CaminhoDoTemplateAjustado= Mid(CaminhoDoTemplate,1,InStrRev(CaminhoDoTemplate,"\"))
    NomeDoArquivo= "evento.htm"
    CaminhoDoArquivo= Server.MapPath(NomeDoArquivo)

    Set ManipulacaoDeArquivo= Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ObjetoArquivo= ManipulacaoDeArquivo.OpenTextFile(CaminhoDoTemplate, 1)
    DadosDoObjetoArquivo= ObjetoArquivo.ReadAll
    ObjetoArquivo.Close

    DadosDoObjetoArquivo= Replace(DadosDoObjetoArquivo, "[Cliente]", Um)

    Set ObjetoArquivo= ManipulacaoDeArquivo.CreateTextFile(CaminhoDoTemplateAjustado & NomeDoArquivo)
    ObjetoArquivo.Write(DadosDoObjetoArquivo)

    Set ObjetoArquivo= ManipulacaoDeArquivo.OpenTextFile(CaminhoDoTemplateAjustado & NomeDoArquivo, 1)
    DadosDoObjetoArquivo= ObjetoArquivo.ReadAll

    Dim objCDOSYSMail
    Dim objCDOSYSCon

    Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration")

    objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.server.com"
    objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "user_id"
    objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
    objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30
    objCDOSYSCon.Fields.update

    Set objCDOSYSMail.Configuration = objCDOSYSCon
    objCDOSYSMail.From = "ABC <abc@server.com>"
    objCDOSYSMail.To = "sender@gmail.com"
    objCDOSYSMail.Subject = "Contato"
    objCDOSYSMail.HTMLBody= DadosDoObjetoArquivo
    objCDOSYSMail.Send

    Set objCDOSYSMail = Nothing
    Set objCDOSYSCon = Nothing
%>
```

I would like to make this simple, skiping the step of generating the file in the disk. I would like to:

Read a Database, reads a template, put data in memory, send the mail with that data in memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I see it correctly, all you have to do is skip the part where you save the file and re-read it... I have refactored your code, gave the variables some english names so I could see what's going on, and commented out the lines you don't need:

```
<%
    Dim TemplateName     : TemplateName = "template.htm"
    Dim TemplateFullPath : TemplateFullPath = Server.MapPath(TemplateName)
    Dim TemplatePath     : TemplatePath = Mid(TemplateFullPath,1,InStrRev(TemplateFullPath,"\"))

    Dim ArchiveName      : ArchiveName = "evento.htm"
    Dim ArchiveFullPath  : ArchiveFullPath = Server.MapPath(ArchiveName)

    Dim FSO, TemplateFile, TemplateText
    Set FSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set TemplateFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(TemplateFullPath, 1)
            TemplateText = TemplateFile.ReadAll()
            TemplateText = Replace(TemplateText, "[Cliente]", Um)
            TemplateFile.Close()

'   Really simple - to do this in-memory, simply don't save and re-read the file....

'        Set TemplateFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(TemplatePath & ArchiveName)
'            TemplateFile.Write(TemplateText)

'        Set TemplateFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(TemplatePath & ArchiveName, 1)
'            TemplateText = TemplateFile.ReadAll


        Set TemplateFile = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing

    Dim objCDOSYSMail, objCDOSYSCon
    Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration")
            objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.server.com"
            objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
            objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
            objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "user_id"
            objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
            objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30
            objCDOSYSCon.Fields.update

            Set objCDOSYSMail.Configuration = objCDOSYSCon
                objCDOSYSMail.From = "ABC <abc@server.com>"
                objCDOSYSMail.To = "sender@gmail.com"
                objCDOSYSMail.Subject = "Contato"
                objCDOSYSMail.HTMLBody= TemplateText
                objCDOSYSMail.Send
            Set objCDOSYSMail.Configuration =  Nothing
        Set objCDOSYSMail = Nothing
    Set objCDOSYSCon = Nothing
%>
```

Hope this helps,

Erik

Comment: thanks for the anwser and for been so kinda. have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

you could use several techniques:

- write your own stringbuilder class
- use the .net system.io.stringwriter class (yes you can use this from classic asp)
- use the adodb.stream object

**example stringwriter:**

```
set sw = server.createObject("system.io.stringwriter")
sw.write_12( DadosDoObjetoArquivo )

objCDOSYSMail.HTMLBody = sw.getStringBuilder().toString()
```

**example (adodb.stream):**

```
set stream = server.createobject("ADODB.Stream")
with stream 
    .Open
    .WriteText DadosDoObjetoArquivo
end with

objCDOSYSMail.HTMLBody = stream.ReadText
stream.Close
```